# Onload for textbox Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have some textboxes that have some javascript onlick's on them and they work fine.  What I want to do is run those (toggleColumn's) function's the first time when the page load to produce the same effect as the checkboxes being pressed after the page loads up ...thanks:

```
       <c:if test="${columnA == 'MWS' || columnB == 'MWS'}">
    <td class="right" style="padding-left: 20px;">MWS</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="hider" value="initial" checked="checked" onclick="javascript:toggleColumn('initialCol');"/></td>
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${columnA == 'SMC Unfunded' || columnB == 'SMC Unfunded'}">
    <td class="right" style="padding-left: 20px;">SMC/ELMP&nbsp;Unfunded</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="hider" value="initial" checked="checked" onclick="javascript:toggleColumn('smcUnfundedCol');"/></td>
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${columnA == 'SMC Funded' || columnB == 'SMC Funded'}">
    <td class="right" style="padding-left: 20px;">SMC/ELMP&nbsp;Funded</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="hider" value="initial" checked="checked" onclick="javascript:toggleColumn('smcFundedCol');"/></td>
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${columnA == 'MMC' || columnB == 'MMC'}">
    <td class="right" style="padding-left: 20px;">MMC</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="hider" value="initial" checked="checked" onclick="javascript:toggleColumn('targetCol');"/></td>
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${columnA == 'Current Scenario' || columnB == 'Current Scenario'}">
    <td class="right" style="padding-left: 20px;">Current Scenario</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="hider" value="initial" checked="checked" onclick="javascript:toggleColumn('currentCol');"/></td>
    </c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function in your  section of your html document

```
<script language="text/javascript">
    function toggleAll(){
        toggleColumn('initialCol');
        toggleColumn('smcUnfundedCol');
        etc...
    }
</script>
```

In your body tag of your HTML, you call the function:

```
<body onload="toggleAll()">
```

Comment: I cant use the body section because it's a include used on many pages

Comment: perhaps you could explore using jquery - by using the built in $(document).ready function that will fire when the page is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can call these function using onLoad in body section.

```
<body onLoad="javascript:toggleColumn('initialCol');">
</body>
```

Comment: I cant use the body section because it's a include used on many pages

Comment: The best option would be to generate the content on the server side itself the way you want to look them first time after page loads.